# How can I drag stage only x axis in Konva.js

Tags: konvajs

When I drag a stage, stage moves only x-axis.

But konva.js docs doesn't have  explanation about it..

Just modify Konva.js sources about drag and i use it?

Or I missed something?

Answer (score 6):

I've found it..

```
var stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight,
        draggable: true,
        dragBoundFunc: (pos) => {
            return {
                x : pos.x,
                y : 0
            }
        }
    });
```

it's done.

Answer (score 1):

The two drag bounds examples explain how to constrain the movement of a draggable element.

[Simple Drag Bounds Tutorial](https://konvajs.github.io/docs/drag_and_drop/Simple_Drag_Bounds.html)

[Complex Drag and Drop Bounds](https://konvajs.org/docs/drag_and_drop/Complex_Drag_and_Drop.html)

As you have found this approach can be used on the stage.